# How to add prometheus data source for grafana with helm?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I tried many sources like `http://prometheus-server.default:9090` but I receive a `HTTP Error Bad Gateway`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found.

The server HTTP URL provided by helm prometheus package for grafana is:
**`http://prometheus-server`**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just use http://localhost:9090 no need to use http://prometheus-server.default:9090, if you have your promitheus in some other server use ip or domain then

Comment: it doesn't work. as stated in the question, it's loaded with helm on a kubernetes cluster, not on localhost